# Gutenprint plugin for GIMP

Tags: plugins, gimp

I would like to install the Gutenprint plugin for GIMP. The documentation shows a screenshot

[image: Gimp Gutenprint Plugin Screenshot]

I downloaded the source code of Gutenprint 5.3 and build it, all without errors.

I installed a printer in CUPS and the driver seems as it should be and it was printing.

But when I open GIMP 2.8 and open File/Print the dialog is exactly the CUPS dialog. It's nothing like the screenshot.

The documentation does not say anything about how to activate or access the Gimp plugin. I do not know anything about Gimp plugins. Maybe I am missing something obvious.

I am using Xubuntu 18.04, but this should be also valid for other versions.

Comment: Leave open. All flavors of an Ubuntu LTS are supported by Ask Ubuntu for 5 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than build the package from source code, I suggest that you open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp-gutenprint
```

Several dependencies will also be installed.

Once completed, a new selection will be available in Gimp: File > Print with Gutenprint...

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Indeed that did install the print dialog in the screenshot. So now I know how it looks like and that it adds a new entry in the file menu. For Bionic is does install V5.2.13. For getting a newer release I would rather like to get the installation working. But maybe you got me to the point to figure out the difference myself.

Answer (score 0):

Just and added info. with the above the gutenprint drivers are available only for Gimp not for any other program.

To also install the CUPS Gutenprint drivers you must also install this

```
 sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint
```

Ony they you also get the choices to select the improved drivers. They all have "CUPS" and "Gutenprint" in the same.